# Как сделать чтобы в JTextPane при использовании JScrollPane значение после пробела не уходили вертикально вниз

Tags: java

Не могу понять почему после пробела, он не использует горизонтальную прокрутку а скидывает её в вертикальную.

[image: Красный прямоугольник указывает на что я имею ввиду.]

Вот кусок кода:

```
    JTextPane textPane= new JTextPane();
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    jsp.setHorizontalScrollBar(new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL));
    jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте для Ваших целей воспользоваться JTextArea.

```
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    jsp.setHorizontalScrollBar(new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL));
    jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

В ней реализуется необходимое Вам поведение.

Comment: Это работает! Большое спасибо!